# How to run Gunicorn concurrently with an infinite loop?

Tags: python, multithreading, gunicorn, bottle

I have a python script in which a loop needs to run forever. In the same script I run Gunicorn to run a bottle.py application. My problem is when I start the script from terminal console, either the Gunicorn web server runs or the infinite loop. Never both.
If I make the script like this: (let's say version A)

```
Def run_forever()
    while true:
    '''check values of some variables and call other functions for actions'''

p_run_forever = threading.Thread(target=run_forever)
p_run_forever.start()
p_run_forever.daemon = True
run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80, server='gunicorn', workers=4)
```

The run_forever() runs only once and after Gunicorn starts , it never runs again. If I make the script like this: (let's say version B)

```
Def run_forever()
    while true:
    '''check values of some variables and call other functions for actions'''

run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80, server='gunicorn', workers=4)
p_run_forever = threading.Thread(target=run_forever)
p_run_forever.daemon = True # If this is false, the script gets locked and I have to close the terminal window
p_run_forever.start()
```

Gunicorn starts but the run_forever() never gets executed. I tried to put Gunicorn inside a thread but it complains that the signal can only run in the main thread.
So what am I doing wrong? How can I make both Gunicorn and my infinite loop run simultaneously without blocking each other?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What is your loop doing? Do these things really need to be in the same process?

Comment: Daniel thank you for your query. The run_forever function monitors some variables in an infinite loop. When a button on the web page (Gunicorn) is clicked, the values of some variables change and when these variables change the run_forever function calls some other functions in the script to take some actions. So the web page (Gunicorn) and the run_forever function must coexist and run simultaneously. That is the reason I put the run_forever function in a thread.

Comment: That seems an odd way to do it. Why not trigger the action in response to the specific post?

Comment: I know it sounds odd :) Let me try to explain: The script runs when the computer boots. It looks into a specific directory picks up a random file and feeds it to the serial port line by line. When the file is finished it picks up another one and does it all over again. Forever. But when a button is clicked (POST event) the script, according to which button is clicked, may stop feeding lines completely, stop feeding the current line and goto next random file or feed a specific file. So normally this file feeding should continue forever.

Comment: So, taking actions just in response to the POST event is not enough. Forexample: if 'next file' is clicked on web, the script should start feeding the next file. But after that, (if 'stop' is not clicked) it should not stop there. It should pick up another random file and keep on. If I take action just in response to POST, it would feed the next file and stop there.

Comment: "The run_forever() runs only once" - Isn't that the idea? It should run once, and never return. Why do you expect "run_forever" to be called more than once?